# Maximum number of iBeacons which an app can range

Tags: ios, ibeacon

does anyone know the maximum number of iBeacons which an app can range? It seem there is no clue on documentation.

Comment: Unless you work at a factory where they might have 10,000 iBeacons on a shelf, I suspect the answer is "all of them".

Answer (score 1):

We build and test iBeacons at Radius Networks, so we often have many transmitting simultaneously.  I have witnessed iOS and Android devices ranging several dozen at the same time.

There is no hard limit in the operating systems and detection libraries.  You may begin to run into trouble when several hundred are visible simultaneously because your software might slow down when hundreds must be processed every second. (Better make it fast!) Also, radio interference will begin to become problematic with many hundred transmitting in the same place. See [this discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21991/how-many-active-bluetooth-devices-can-i-reliably-detect-in-a-single-space).

One radio interference becomes an issue, expect to see ranging detections happen less often than the once per second nominal rate.